Intermittent Authentication Issue with Google Cloud Vision API for Text Detection in Production Environment
I’m experiencing an intermittent authentication issue with the Google Cloud Vision API when running in production. The service, uses a service account json file for authentication and then perform text detection API via Python’s ImageAnnotatorClient. This works fine on both localhost and the development server. However, in production, it occasionally fails with an authentication error.
2024-08-18 07:16:35,315 - uvicorn - ERROR - Response Message: 401 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED" domain: "googleapis.com" metadata {   key: "service"   value: "vision.googleapis.com" } metadata {   key: "method"   value: "google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotator.BatchAnnotateImages"

Details:
Service Environment: FastAPI service running in production server on virtual machine hosted on a private infrastructure. Its not a cloud based VM.
Problem: The API sometimes returns authentication errors. The issue is intermittent but appears only in the production environment.
Working Conditions: The same service account JSON file works without issues on localhost and dev servers.
Additional Context:

I have validated that the service account credentials and API configurations are correct.
Network issues have been ruled out as the server is capable of making other network requests reliably.

CODE:
Relevant part of the code in the api.
def setup_client(self):
        main_key = Utils.main_key_compile(self.first_key_part_file,self.second_key_part_file,self.third_key_part_file)
        
        # Create a Fernet cipher using the main key
        cipher_suite = Fernet(main_key)

        with open(self.gvk_file_path, "rb") as file:
            encrypted_data = file.read()

        # Read the encrypted content from the JSON file you want to decrypt
        decrypted_data = cipher_suite.decrypt(encrypted_data)

        # client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
        json_str = decrypted_data.decode("utf-8")  # Decode the bytes to a string
        api_key_dict = json.loads(json_str)  # Parse the JSON string into a Python dictionary
        my_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(api_key_dict)
        self.client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=my_credentials)

    def extract_text_google(self, image):
        success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.png', image)
        content = encoded_image.tobytes()
        image = vision.Image(content=content)
        image_context = types.ImageContext(language_hints=["en"])
        max_retries = 2
        retry_delay = 2  # seconds
        for attempt in range(max_retries):
            try:
                response = self.client.text_detection(image=image,image_context=image_context)
                # check if response.text_annotations is empty   
                if len(response.text_annotations) == 0:
                    text_results = {}
                else:
                    text_results = response.text_annotations[0].description
                return text_results

            except google.api_core.exceptions.Unauthenticated as e:
                self.logger.error(f"Authentication error: {e}")
                # Optionally, reinitialize the client here if needed
                self.setup_client()

            except google.api_core.exceptions.GoogleAPIError as e:
                self.logger.error(f"API error: {e}")
                if attempt < max_retries:
                    time.sleep(retry_delay)
                else:
                    raise
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
                if attempt < max_retries:
                    time.sleep(retry_delay)
                else:
                    raise

        return {}

Also rarely face the following issue as well
gunicorn[3784527]: google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:142.250.181.74:443: Failed to connect to remote host: FD Shutdown

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that the service account JSON file is correctly configured.
Attempted to resolve the issue by creating multiple service accounts, but the problem persists.
Ran a simple test on the prod server, by creating a vision client on python and hitting the api with service account credentials, this time continuously received failed authentication.
TroubleShooting_Simple_API_Hit_Client 

I expected that direct call with client should work atleast sometime, since calls from within fastapi service sometimes worked, but this time got authentication issue every single time.

If (you don't describe where "in production" is) you're running on a Google compute service, then you shouldn't store Service Account keys in a secret manager. The behavior is redundant and doesn't increase security in this case. If you're running on a Google compute service, you should (!) leverage Application Default Credentials and its ability to use the identity from the running service.

Sorry, i didn't mention that the production server is hosted on a private infrastructure, no on any cloud platform. I know the approach is not a good one. But it was working atleast, now due to the intermittent nature of the issue, i'm unable to diagnose the problem.

Please don't misunderstand me. If you're running on Google Cloud (or Workload Identity Federation), then using ADC makes sense. If not (as you are) then using a Secret Manager is a good solution.

Is your local environment a good proxy for production? Are you able to reflect similar load, networking and errors? Can you quantify the problem? How many requests are being made? How many fail? How often does the failure occur? etc.

The access token will expire every hour (3600s) but should be refreshed by the client. The client only attempts refreshes before calls are made to the service so, if you have extended gaps between client.text_detection, the access token may have expired and need to be refreshed. This should succeed even after the access token has expired but it may be interesting to know the periodicity of calls and match this to the expiry event.
